# How do I remove 127.0.0.1 from PHP email headers?

Tags: php, email

I'm using the simplest possible version of the mail command.  The header comes back as follows:

Received: from wordswithfriends.net (wordswithfriends.net [127.0.0.1])

How do I get rid of 127.0.0.1?  I'm not sure whether to start with PHP or the server.  I have full control of both.

Comment: Why remove it? It's not exactly leaking any earthshaking private info that your computer has 127.0.0.1 as the localhost address, like every other computer out there.

Comment: I'm worried it might be triggering spam filters

Answer (score 1):

It depends what software you are using to relay the mail, and how this is configured.

The mail commands in PHP outsources the sending of mail to another program. In my experience, configuring the hostname with the IP of your server should fix this problem. Here is an example from a Ubuntu configuration manual:

https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/email-services.html

Search for "hostname". Generally this needs to be configured on both the relay and machine level, e.g.

http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/07/how-to-change-the-hostname-of-a-linux-system/

I'm not sure what system you're using, but in my experience with Linux/Windows operating systems, this should solve your problem. It should also prevent SPF related issues.

Comment: Also, from memory it is a good idea to add the IP of the domain to the host file (e.g. /etc/hosts) to make sure it is handled internally, e.g.http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=3407